# Which gems can a Rails app survive without?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, minimize

- actionmailer
- actionpack
- activeresource
- activesupport

I have a basic scaffolded CRUD app that uses ActiveRecord to connect to a SQLite database and I have frozen my Rails gems.

**Which of these gems could I delete without affecting my app?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ActionMailer can go if you'll never use e-mail, and ActiveResource is just a more REST-ful API to Rails than ActiveRecord is. You'll need the rest:

- ActionPack handles the split of web requests to controllers and views
- ActiveSupport puts a lot of mixins and syntactic sugar from Ruby into Rails

But more importantly, why do you need to delete the gems? It's not like they take up a lot of space.

Comment: That's a pretty interesting question. I would make a new one asking that question specifically. Good luck!

Comment: Actually, ActiveSupport doesn't make "life easier". Its a requirement. It's basically the library that bundles all Ruby extensions that are used in Rails.

Comment: ActiveResource is not a replacement for ActiveRecord! ActiveResource allows you to consume RESful web services using an ActiveRecord like API.

Comment: @Skade, @John: Yes, I didn't phrase that very well. But my point was that ARes isn't strictly required (you don't have to use a RESTful API). I noted that ActiveSupport is one of the required pieces, since you need those extensions in Rails.

Comment: Perhaps he doesn't want to actually delete the gems, just exclude them from environment.rb so they're not loaded...?